# How to add multible accepted variables to Tag

Tags: azure, variables, tags

I can't figure out a way to assign multible accepted Variables on a single tag.

Say we have "Environment Tag"

I want the only accepted variables to be "Production, Testing, Pending"

However i've only been able to assign one Variable per Tag.

I've tried using pre-built policys and build around them. As i'm fairly new to policies.

I have a tag "Environment"

I've created the tag Environment on the sub, so it appears in the dropdown menu.

I've tried to create multible variables in the variable section, however i can only create one.

I can get it working with one variable, such as production, but if i assign more than one variable in the text box it just adds it as one value, i've tried seperation with ("',;:) Nothing seems to work.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Require tag and its value",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value. Does not apply to resource groups.",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Tags"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Name",
          "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
        }
      },
      "tagValue": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Value",
          "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
          "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62"
}
```

When inputting the TAG, and Variable

```
"parameters": {
  "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Name",
      "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
    }



  "tagValue": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Value",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
    }
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to add a secondary tagvalue "Tagvalue1,2,3 ect"

```
  "tagValue": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Value",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
    }

  "tagValue1": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Value",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'Testing'"
    }
  "tagValue2": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Value",
      "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'Pending'"
    }
```

All other Variables for this tag should be rejected.
However i'm unable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an example from Azure documentation site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-on-resource-groups

If you do not need any parameters for the policy:

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag Environment and its value on resource groups",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
      "mode": "All",
      "parameters": {
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
               },
               {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                   "field": "tags[Environment]",
                   "notEquals": "Production"
                  },
                  {
                   "field": "tags[Environment]",
                   "notEquals": "Testing"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "tags[Environment]",
                    "notEquals": "Pending"
                   }
                 ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

with parameters :

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value on resource groups",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
      "mode": "All",
      "parameters": {
         "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
         },
         "tagValue1": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as production"
            }
         },
         "tagValue2": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as testing"
            }
         },
         "tagValue3": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as pending"
            }
         }
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
               },
               {
                 "anyOf" : [
                 {
                   "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                   "notEquals": "[parameters('tagValue1')]"
                 },
                 {
                   "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                   "notEquals": "[parameters('tagValue2')]"
                 },
                 {
                   "field": "[concat('tags[',parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                   "notEquals": "[parameters('tagValue3')]"
                 }
               ]
              }
            ]
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you are creating a policy from the Azure Portal, you do not need to copy `displayName` and `description` inside `properties`:

[image]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the great input seems very promising, and is essentially what i'd like to do. However i'm getting Invalid JSON error, and a "property properties is not allowed"

https://i.imgur.com/qdsE1MT.png

Comment: @Jokha I have updated my answer, you do not need copy the code with properties, but only properties it self without displayName and description, if you are creating a policy from the Azure Portal. I also had a syntax error, you need {} around anyOf statement, so recopy the corrected code from my answer

Comment: I'm able to import the one with parameters, however not the one without. It gives me the option to predefine what tag and values i'd like as a requirement, however it doesn't appear to enforce the "Deny" When creating a ressource in the scope, i'm not met with an failed validation if I create a resource with tags and values.

The whole purpose was to enforce and make sure 3rd. party consultants make sure to tag ressources correctly, as we use this info in ServiceNow for assigning ownership,state and environment.

I can see the assignment shows as non-compliant. Did i perhaps mess up?

Comment: @Jokha this sample is for Resource Groups, what kind of resource you are creating ?

Comment: @Jokha remove `{
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          }, ` part if you need to apply it on all types of resources, the both policies are working good in my environment. After policy assignment, it could take some time for policy to work up to 10-20 min

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use the `in` property. from examples:

```
"parameters": {
    "allowedLocations": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
            "displayName": "Allowed locations",
            "strongType": "location"
        },
        "defaultValue": [ "westus2" ],
        "allowedValues": [
            "eastus2",
            "westus2",
            "westus"
        ]
    }
}
```

and then you can reference it:

```
{
    "field": "location",
    "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
}
```

Comment: thanks for input, I've read this example, but I'm unsure on how I'd actually implement that into my JSON.

as stated previously, i'm very new to JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags[Environment]",
              "notEquals": "Production"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags[Environment]",
              "notEquals": "Testing"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags[Environment]",
              "notEquals": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

I've gotten this far thanks to your amazing help, however upon validating new VM's i get the following error, despite which value i type: Pending, Testing or Production

```
{
  "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
  "message": "The template deployment failed because of policy violation. Please see details for more information.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "RequestDisallowedByPolicy",
      "target": "tester123",
      "message": "Resource 'tester123' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{\"policyAssignment\":{\"name\":\"Enforce tag Environment\",\"id\":\"/subscriptions/f3434458-6c34-41bf-b159-04eff84fb1b8/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/363b1c045401446eafdd29bf\"},\"policyDefinition\":{\"name\":\"Enforce tag Environment\",\"id\":\"/subscriptions/f3434458-6c34-41bf-b159-04eff84fb1b8/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/7be665bc-57a5-451d-b159-6cabcfd1042a\"}}]'.",
      "additionalInfo": [
        {
          "type": "PolicyViolation",
          "info": {
            "policyDefinitionDisplayName": "Enforce tag Environment",
            "evaluationDetails": {
              "evaluatedExpressions": [
                {
                  "result": "True",
                  "expressionKind": "Field",
                  "expression": "type",
                  "path": "type",
                  "expressionValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                  "targetValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                  "operator": "Equals"
                },
                {
                  "result": "True",
                  "expressionKind": "Field",
                  "expression": "tags[Environment]",
                  "path": "tags[Environment]",
                  "expressionValue": "Testing",
                  "targetValue": "Production",
                  "operator": "NotEquals"
                }
              ]
            },
            "policyDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/f3434458-6c34-41bf-b159-04eff84fb1b8/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/7be665bc-57a5-451d-b159-6cabcfd1042a",
            "policyDefinitionName": "7be665bc-57a5-451d-b159-6cabcfd1042a",
            "policyDefinitionEffect": "deny",
            "policyAssignmentId": "/subscriptions/f3434458-6c34-41bf-b159-04eff84fb1b8/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/363b1c045401446eafdd29bf",
            "policyAssignmentName": "363b1c045401446eafdd29bf",
            "policyAssignmentDisplayName": "Enforce tag Environment",
            "policyAssignmentScope": "/subscriptions/f3434458-6c34-41bf-b159-04eff84fb1b8",
            "policyAssignmentParameters": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

it would appear to me at least, that i fail because of wrong targetvalue. However I'd suppose that anyof the 3 options defined in policy definition would do?
Atleast i figured out how to only target this to our VM's, or at least i think i did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for restricting the values in basics called "**allowedValues**":
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#parameter-properties

```
"parameters": {
    "allowedLocations": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
            "displayName": "Allowed locations",
            "strongType": "location"
        },
        "defaultValue": [ "westus2" ],
        "allowedValues": [
            "eastus2",
            "westus2",
            "westus"
        ]
    }
}
```